# How to configure Fluentd to have Restfull End points / custom logs in Azure Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd, azure-aks

We have installed EFK [Elastic Search, FluentD, Kibana] in the Azure Kubernetes cluster [AKS] using the below article, 
https://dzone.com/articles/kubernetes-logging-and-monitoring-the-elasticsearc-1

EFK is now logging all the Container Logs and we just want to log selective Logs instead of all container logs. 
1. Is there a way to create a method to have specific logs i.e. establishing a REST API or something which takes a custom json
2. How to manage the FluentD Config file with the AKS since it uses HELM to install the EFK stack in the clusters , thanks in advance

Regards
JK

Answer (score 1):

The fluentd Helm chart creates a `ConfigMap` -- that's how you'd manage the configuration.
In more ways than one, the REST endpoint you want is the Kubernetes master and the client you're looking for is kubectl ;-)

Comment: Excellent, can you give me some sample which can help us , especially related to creating a end point for logging rather taking all the " @type stdout". thanks

Comment: @user7403074 I don't understand your question, sorry!